# how to access the neighbor unit in metal kernel function correctly

Tags: ios, macos, shader, metal

I used metal to do some interpolation task. I wrote the kernel function as followed:

```
kernel void kf_interpolation( device short *dst, device uchar *src, uint id [[ thread_position_in_grid ]] )    
{
  dst[id] = src[id-1] + src[id] + src[id+1];
}
```

That kernel function could not gave expected value. And I found the cause was that the src[id-1] was always 0, which was false value. However, src[id+1] contained the right value. The question is how could I use the neighbour unit correctly, e.g. [id-1], in kernel functions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way to handle edge cases like this is usually to grow your source array at each end and offset the indices. So for N calculations, allocate your `src` array with N+2 elements, fill elements 1 through N (inclusive) with the source data, and set element 0 and N+1 to whatever you want the edge condition to be.

Answer (score 0):

An even more efficient method would be to use MTLTextures instead of MTLBuffers. MTLTextures have an addressing mode attached to them which causes the hardware to automatically substitute either zero or the nearest valid texel when you read off the edge of a texture. They can also do linear interpolation in hardware for free, which can be of great help for resampling, assuming bilinear interpolation is good enough for you. If not, I recommend looking at MPSImageLanczosScale as an alternative.

You can make a MTLTexture from a MTLBuffer. The two will alias the same pixel data.

Comment: Thanks @Ollmann. Is MTLTexture suitable for storage of yuv format data, which is common in video coding.

Comment: It can do yuva 444 without too much trouble. Just stick them in there in place of RGBA.  For 422, there is some limited support in the form of MTLPixelFormatGBGR422 / MTLPixelFormatBGRG422. In either case, you have to know the data in the RGB channels are actually YCbCr and do your own YCbCr ->RGB conversion matrix in software when necessary + any video range adjustments required.

Comment: One common YUV format is yuv420, which has 3 channels: y,u, and v. Could I  create 3 MTLTexuture objects for each channel, and do computational task separately?

Comment: How do you achieve linear "interpolation for free" ? Is it done with "samplers" ? Can you give a keyword to for in the metal docs ! Thanks

Comment: Set the filtering mode to linear instead of nearest. If the coordinates are not exactly integer + 0.5 the result will be a bilinear interpolation of the four nearby pixel values.